# Why it is much slower to use mysql to add primary key onto tables than postgres?

Tags: mysql, postgresql

Currently I am using DBGen to generate the database which will be used to generate the TPC-H benchmarks. I am import the files (raw data directly from DBGen) into both mysql and postgres. After the data is imported, I need to add primary key as well as foreign keys onto the existing tables.

I am using the most simple command to add primary keys and foreign keys.

According to my own experience, postgres run much faster than mysql (especially handling big tables, 1.4 GB lineitem table in my case). 
But does anyone know why it is the case?
Does it mean that the two systems do something very differently when they are trying to add primary key or foreign keys?

Comment: Could you show us what exactly this "most simple command" is? And do you have any numbers for "much faster"? And what is the structure of the tables you are adding keys to? How many rows are there (vs how many GB of data)?

Comment: ALTER TABLE TPCH.lineitem ADD PRIMARY KEY (l_orderkey, l_linenumber);

Comment: The time for mysql to execute the above command is 23min, I could not remember how long it takes for postgres to execute it, but pretty sure that the time is much shorter.

Comment: The row number is 12 million with 16 columns (4 int, 4 decimal, 3 date, 5 char/string, totally round 80 chars);

Answer (score 2):

When you add and remove PRIMARY KEYs in MySQL, it rebuilds the entire table -- so effectively re-imports it by making a copy of it.

In addition to being a general limitation (this happens with MyISAM too), InnoDB is stored as a "Clustered Primary Key", that is, the rows are internally stored in a tree based on the primary key.. so the primary key is integral to how the table is stored, and sorted... so even if it could somehow do this without copying everything it would have to basically completely re-organise everything anyway.

See: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-index-types.html

I would suggest adding the PRIMARY KEY before you import the data, so that you only need to do it once.

You should be able to add secondary indexes and foreign key references online, without a table copy.  See:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-create-index-overview.html
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-create-index-limitations.html